# Match values by string containing another string

Tags: r, string-matching

I have two dataframes. The first looks like this:

```
month     Joanne K. Rowling   Samuel L. Jackson
2000/01   1                   0
2000/02   1                   1
2000/03   0                   1
2000/04   0                   0
2000/05   0                   1
2000/06   1                   0
```

> test_1<-data.frame("Month"=c("2000/01","2000/02","2000/03","2000/04","2000/05","2000/06"),"Joanne K. Rowling"=c(1,1,0,0,0,1),"Samuel L. Jackson"=c(0,1,1,0,1,0))

The other looks like this

```
Name            Score
Samuel Jackson  67
Joanne Rowling  52
```

> test_2<-data.frame("Name"=c("Samuel Jackson","Joanne Rowling"),"Score"=c(67,52))

I'd like to combine them in order to obtain the following data frame

```
month     Joanne K. Rowling   Samuel L. Jackson
2000/01   52                   0
2000/02   52                   67
2000/03   0                    67
2000/04   0                    0
2000/05   0                    67
2000/06   52                   0
```

Where the value 1 is replaced by the score in test_2. The colnames from test_1 may differ slightly from the values in table_2, so the match should not be fixed. I found a way to do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(test_2)) {
  for(k in 1:ncol(test_1){
    for(l in 1:nrow(test_1)){
      if(grepl(test_2[i,6],as.data.frame(colnames(test_1))[k,1])) {
        if(test_1[l,k]==1){
          test_1[l,k]<-test_2[i,5]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is very inefficient, as I have to apply this to a list of dataframes.
Please, try to write an efficient way with less loops as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `grepl` would directly work here as `'Joanne Rowling'` will not match with `'Joanne K. Rowling'`. You may use `stringdist::stringdistmatrix` to get the matches and then multiply the corresponding values.

```
mat <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(names(test_1)[-1], test_2$Name)
test_1[-1] <- sweep(test_1[-1], 2, test_2$Score[max.col(-mat)], `*`)
test_1

#    Month Joanne K. Rowling Samuel L. Jackson
#1 2000/01                52                 0
#2 2000/02                52                67
#3 2000/03                 0                67
#4 2000/04                 0                 0
#5 2000/05                 0                67
#6 2000/06                52                 0
```

---

To apply this to multiple dataframes you can do :

```
lapply(test_1_list, function(x) {
  mat <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(names(x)[-1], test_2$Name)
  x[-1] <- sweep(x[-1], 2, test2$Score[max.col(-mat)], `*`)
  x
}) -> result
result
```

where `test_1_list` are list of dataframes.

**data**

```
test_1<-data.frame("Month"=c("2000/01","2000/02","2000/03","2000/04","2000/05","2000/06"),
                   "Joanne K. Rowling"=c(1,1,0,0,0,1),
                   "Samuel L. Jackson"=c(0,1,1,0,1,0), check.names = FALSE)
test_2<-data.frame("Name"=c("Samuel Jackson","Joanne Rowling"),"Score"=c(67,52))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` function and define an index vector that decides which values shall be replaced:

```r
# Just for JK Rowling
test_1[,2] <- replace(test_1[,2], test_1[,2] == 1, test_2[2,2])
```

`test_1[,2] == 1` creates an index vector that is `TRUE` for the 1's and `FALSE` for the 0's.

It would then be possible to just duplicate the line for Samuel Jackson.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I have many more names than these, so it'd be impractical for me to create a single line for each of them.